# Jquery hide/show messing up

Tags: jquery

Hey everyone I have a script problem once again. I'm doing a jQuery show/hide for my members profile data in post. Please visit http://www.pimpkings.com/t3-what-up-everyone to see what i'm talking about, I'm leaving the code on so you can see what it's doing.

Every time I click on one persons show/hide it opens everyones and i only want it to open 1 persons at users request.

codes are-

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".slidingDiv").hide();
 $(".show_hide").show();
    $('.show_hide').click(function(){

$(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();

});

});
</script>
```

Then the html coding is

```
<span class="show_hide" style="cursor:pointer;color:#c0c0c0;">Show/hide</span>
<div class="slidingDiv">
                              <!-- BEGIN profile_field -->
                            <center>    {postrow.displayed.profile_field.LABEL} <center/>
                            <center>  {postrow.displayed.profile_field.CONTENT} <center/>
                            <center>  {postrow.displayed.profile_field.SEPARATOR}<center/>
                            <!-- END profile_field -->
                            <center>{postrow.displayed.profile_field.LABEL}<center/>
                            <center>Online Status<center/><br/>
                            <center>{postrow.displayed.ONLINE_IMG}<center/>
                                        {postrow.displayed.POSTER_RPG} <br />

                            <!-- BEGIN contact_field -->
                             <br/> <br/>
                            {postrow.displayed.PROFILE_IMG} {postrow.displayed.PM_IMG}  
                            {postrow.displayed.EMAIL_IMG} {postrow.displayed.contact_field.CONTENT}
                            <!-- END contact_field -->
                              <span class="show_hide" style="cursor:pointer;color:#c0c0c0;">hide</span></div>
                            </span>
```

Can anyone help figure out another selector so it does not open all at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();
    $('.show_hide').click(function() {
        $(this).next(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });
});​
```

Note that you should probably change the class of the "hide" link at the end of the profile to something else (e.g just hide) so that you can more easily target it with jQuery to hide the profile.

Oh and one other thing, the `<center>` tag was deprecated a long time ago. Use CSS to center instead.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gswn9/)**

Comment: Haha     <center> that was deprecated wow, shows how long its been since Ive been programming. I started when i was 12, when html had half the deprecated elements. Way before half these languages were created. I'll try it and let you know thanks

Comment: Thanks man it works. I'd upvote this but can't. Can you explain a little how that worked so wonderfully? is $(this).next what created it to open one at a time?

Comment: Yes, this refers to the element being clicked on so the other code is relative to that specific element instead of all elements with a certain class.

Comment: Ok thank you again. Now I have one more question, I'm trying to make a ul list for navigation, that'll open "windows". problem is this does not work for what I need. Since I belive when I make the li have class="show_hide" and close off the ul it makes it basically broken. Any advice?

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure what the issue is based on your comment. You might want to start a new question here though if this is a separate issue.

Comment: ok thanks again. If you can give me a minute i'll set up a jsfiddle and a new question and give u the link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334744/jquery-show-hide-feature-broken-from-ul

theres the link my friend