# jQuery show/hide feature broken from ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to hide my divs which will have content in them when finished. I have a jsFiddle file and some of the coding is not complete, just wrote it very fast to give you an idea.

http://jsfiddle.net/vCZC7/

I believe that the ul is making it not be created correctly.

Comment: Your question is about jQuery, but in [your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vCZC7/) you are using Mootools 1.4.5. That may be at least one of the reasons why it is not working properly ;)

Comment: The jsfiddle properly showing what you have now is this, I suppose: http://jsfiddle.net/vCZC7/2/

Comment: Yeah guys sorry I didnt know you had to chose a one of those...I don't know what Mootools 1.4.5 is honestly. I'm just learning jQuery

Comment: No problem. Mootools is alternative framework, some say even better than jQuery (as a matter of fact, jQuery is more like a set of functions than a framework, Mootools alters more the way JavaScript behaves). You do not need Mootools now, but it is worth to know it exists, and that it overrides `$` symbol ;)

Answer (score 0):

The html in your fiddle is invalid: you should not assign the same `id` attribute to multiple elements. If you try to do something like `$("#slidingDiv").hide();` it will only select the *first* (in most browsers) element with that id to hide.

Also you are using the `".show_hide"` class selector but none of your elements have that class.

Within your click handler you've said `$(this).next("#slidingDiv").slideToggle();` but the `.next()` method doesn't go looking for the next element that has the supplied id, it selects only the immediately following element if that element has the supplied id.

Also you've used jsfiddle incorrectly: within the JavaScript window you are supposed to put JavaScript code, not `<script>` tags. You should remove the `<script>` tags and instead select the required library from the panel on the left, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/vCZC7/1/ (Your fiddle had the default Mootools library selected on the left.)

I found your explanation of the required behaviour somewhat lacking, but here is a working fiddle where clicking the li elements toggles the divs underneath: http://jsfiddle.net/vCZC7/3/ (note: I updated it to use the latest jQuery because the simplest thing seemed to be to use the `.index()` method syntax introduced in version 1.4 and you had only included 1.3.2).

Comment: Good answer. OP needed to post jsfiddle using proper library and proper wrapping of the actual script (on the left you can choose "on Dom Ready", so you do not need to wrap it yourself).

Comment: Thanks @Tadeck. I know about the on ready option jsfiddle offers, but where the person asking the question has explicitly included `$(document).ready(` in their code I generally do the same in my own fiddle and use the "no wrap" option - otherwise inevitably I get a comment that _my_ code doesn't work because it got copied out of the fiddle and used without a ready handler...

Comment: yeah I don't know everything about the fiddle. thats my bad guys. So nnnn the ("selector").click(function() thats what handles what to click? YEah i know the script probably would be messed up, I copy and pasted it so I can quickly show what I wanted. How to handle so only one is opened?

Comment: _"How to handle so only one is opened?"_ Do you mean "so only one is open at a time"?

Comment: There's lots of ways to do that. Here's one: `$('.slidingDiv').slideUp().eq($(this).index()).slideDown();` (i.e., slide them all up and then just slide down the selected one). http://jsfiddle.net/vCZC7/4/